# Modifying tree Graphs

Tags: co.combinatorics, graph-theory, trees

Please consider a tree graph. There is one unique path connecting any two vertices.

However, I wonder how to address the following question:

Starting from a generic tree, is there an algorithmic way to connect any two nodes of the tree with $M$ unique paths such that no two paths contain the same edge? How can the total number of edges in the modified graph be kept a minimum?

I trying to answer this from a network-engineer's perspective. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes.  See the paper [Minimum augmentation of a tree to a K-edge-connected graph](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/net.3230180104/abstract) by Ueno, Kajitani and Wada.